# Optimal way to free() a malloc'ed 2D array in C

Tags: c, arrays, memory, pointers, free

Supposing I have a 2 dimensional array which was created with something like this,

```
char **foo = (char **) malloc(height * sizeof(char *));
for(i = 0; i <= height; i++) 
    foo[i] = (char *) malloc (width * sizeof(char *));
```

First of all, Is this even the right way to create an array like this?. The catch here is, 'height' and 'width' is something that is set during runtime.

This seems to work, but which is the best strategy to free this 2d array.
free(funge) sounds wrong. Going by some other posts in here, I guess I will have free *each* row one by one?

I did try something like this,

```
for (height = 0; height < ip_ptr->funge_height; height++) {
    free(funge[height]);
} 
free(funge)
```

This, however gives me a double free pointer exception. Does this mean, I don't have to manage this piece of memory?. I was of the impression that, for every malloc'ed memory we should call free().

Comment: That should work if height in the first code is the same value as ip_ptr->funge_height in the second

Comment: If width is constant, is there something preventing you from doing `char **foo = (char **) calloc(height * width * sizeof(char));` ?

Comment: @tordek: yes - he can't then write funge[i][j]; he has to write funge[i*width+j];

Comment: There's no need to cast the return value from `malloc`.

Comment: Actually, there are several things wrong there.  First, calloc() takes two parameters.  Second, it returns a pointer to a block of memory just as malloc(), so it won't be the char** you're expecting.  But also, your char**foo won't even work as tordek suggests, with foo[i*width+j].

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since all the 'rows' are the same size, you can just allocate it in one swoop, with `malloc(height * width * sizeof (char *))` (it's not entirely clear whether you're creating a 2d array of `char` or a 2d array of `char *`).  You can use multiplication to calculate the appropriate index (i.e. `foo[i][j]` becomes `foo + i * height + j`),

`free()`ing it will similarly, take a single call.

Answer (score 8):

In the for loop for allocation you are using `i <= height;` instead of `i < height;`. So you are writing to an invalid memory location and the behavior of your code becomes unpredictable.

Comment: So, how does that ansewer a question titled "Optimal way...". Did you mean "crash free" by "optimal"?

Answer (score 7):

The second allocation should be:

```
foo[i] = (char *) malloc (width * sizeof(char));
```

you're also looping `height+1` times while allocating.

Besides that, those two snippets seem right to me, so the error should be elsewhere.

If the array was allocated as just one big chunk of memory, then you'd have to free it just once.

```
char **foo = (char **) malloc(height * sizeof(char *));
*foo = malloc(height * width * sizeof(char))
for (int i = 1; i < height; i++) {
  foo[i] = *foo + i*width;
}
//and you just do 2 frees
free(*foo);
free(foo);
```

Comment: This is a much faster way to do this, calls to malloc aren't free. Repeatedly calling malloc/free can also increase memory fragmentation, which will further slow down allocations.

Answer (score 3):

The mechanism to allocate is OK (though you should use `sizeof(char)` instead of `sizeof(char *)` in the allocate loop; you are overallocating the character strings) given that width and height are runtime values.

Your impression that you should call free() once for each malloc() is basically correct (things like calloc() and realloc() complicate the simple story).

The loop followed by free should be correct (or, at least, the general mechanism of 'free the sub-arrays first, then the array of pointers to sub-arrays) - so you need to review where the double free error is coming from.  We can't see where the `ip_ptr->funge_height` was controlled; it is not immediately obvious that `funge` is described by `ip_ptr->funge_height`.

---

See the answer from 'unknown @ google' - there's an array bounds problem.

Comment: For what it's worth, I'm not sure anything in the standard really guarantees that `sizeof(char *) == sizeof(char **)` - you might want to consider that a bug.

Comment: There is a guarantee that pointers to objects are all of the same size.  There isn't a guarantee in the C standard that pointers to functions are the same size as pointers to objects; POSIX provides that guarantee instead.

Comment: Somewhere down the code, I do set ip_ptr->funge_height and ip_ptr->funge_width to the values for height and width. Hence these two are the same. But yeah, the array bounds problem was a noob mistake.

Answer (score 2):

When you allocate the memory, it should be `i < height` as the loop condition.

When you deallocate the memory, you should iterate up to the same index as you did when allocating.  `ip_ptr->funge_height` should be the same as the original `height`, but it's not obviously so.

Other than that, it should work.

Here's another way, that involves fewer mallocs and frees.

To allocate:

```
char **foo = malloc (height * sizeof (char **));
foo[0] = malloc (height * width * sizeof (char *));
for (i = 1;  i < height;  ++i) {
    foo[i] = foo[i-1] + width;
}
```

To deallocate:

```
free (foo[0]);
free (foo);
```

Comment: you shouldn't multiply the width times the sizeof(char*), the compiler already does that for you if the pointer is correctly typed.

Answer (score 0):

Allocation (assuming height > 0 and width > 0)

```
char **foo, *row;

assert(height > 0 && width > 0);
foo = malloc(height * sizeof *foo);
row = malloc(height * width * sizeof *row);
assert(foo != NULL && row != NULL);

for (i = 0; i < height; ++i, row += width) 
  foo[i] = row;

assert(row == *foo + height * width);
```

Deallocation

```
assert(foo != NULL);
free(*foo);
free(foo);
```

Answer (score 0):

In such cases you can always use valgrind. Just compile your executable and run it:

```
valgrind --leak-check=full ./a.out
```

Valgrind will find all your memory validations and point to the code lines involved.

In your case it may have find the indexing problem (< vs. <=) easily.

Answer (score 0):

If your compiler supports it, you could use a pointer to a variable-length array, ie

```
size_t width = 10, height = 5;
char *(*foo)[height][width] = malloc(sizeof *foo);
```

Keep in mind that you'll have to derefence the pointer before accessing the array elements, eg

```
(*foo)[1][2] = "foo";
```

This has the benefit that you'll only allocate a single, continuous block of memory which can be deallocated with a single call fo `free()`.

Answer (score 0):

This 100% works without exe crash.

```
char **map2d;
map2d=(char **)malloc(MAXY*sizeof(char *));
for(int a=0; a<MAXY; a++)
    map2d[a]=(char *)malloc(MAXX*sizeof(char));
for(int a=0; a<MAXX; a++)
    free(map2d[a]);
free(map2d);
```