# 2d array of struct -- malloc() and free()

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, malloc, free

```
#pragma pack(push, 1)
typedef struct 
{
      /*...*/
  unsigned int      dataoffset;         //No of bytes before actual pixel data
}HEADER;

typedef struct 
{
   /*...*/
   unsigned int     width;
   unsigned int     height;
   unsigned short   bits_per_pixel;         //code is written for 24 bits only and No other format is supported..
    /*...*/
}INFO_HEADER;

typedef struct 
{
   unsigned char    b;
   unsigned char    g;
   unsigned char    r;        
}COLORMAP;

#pragma pack(pop)


int main()
{
      // Var decl.
  INFO_HEADER       *pHeader = NULL;
  FILE              *pImage;
  COLORMAP          **ppColors;
  /*...*/

/* File opened in read, binary mode, memory allocated for pHeader*/     

fread (pHeader, sizeof(INFO_HEADER), 1, pImage);  

/*Next block is actually problematic.. Posting 'as is' from my code*/
      ppColors = (COLORMAP**)malloc((pHeader -> height ) * sizeof(COLORMAP));
  for(i = 0 ; i < pHeader -> height ; i++)
     ppColors[i] = (COLORMAP*)malloc(pHeader -> width * sizeof(COLORMAP));
fseek(pImage, pHeader -> fileheader.dataoffset, SEEK_SET);
    for (i = 0 ; i < pHeader -> width ; i++) 
  {
      for (j = 0 ; j < pHeader -> height ; j++) 
      {
          fread(&b, sizeof(unsigned char), 1, pImage);
          fread(&g, sizeof(unsigned char), 1, pImage);
          fread(&r, sizeof(unsigned char), 1, pImage);

          ppColors[i][j].b = b;
          ppColors[i][j].g = g;
          ppColors[i][j].r = r; 

          printf("width = %d height = %d %d:\t", i, j,  cnt);
          printf("%d ", (int)ppColors[i][j].b);
          printf("%d ", (int)ppColors[i][j].g);
          printf("%d\n", (int)ppColors[i][j].r);
          cnt++;  
      }
  }

  /*And at last free()ing..*/
  for(i = 0 ; i < pHeader -> height ; i++)        free(ppColors[i]);
   free(ppColors);
  cleanup();
  return(0)
}
```

**Possible Duplicate**: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1568042/optimal-way-to-free-a-malloced-2d-array-in-c

Though above link could not solve my problems.

1. I run out of memory. I have malloc()ed for height, then for each of the height, width is again malloc()ed. I am trying to work on width X height domain only. It seems that problem is with height. If you change

`ppColors = (COLORMAP**)malloc((pHeader -> height ) * sizeof(COLORMAP));` to
`ppColors = (COLORMAP**)malloc((pHeader -> height + 6 ) * sizeof(COLORMAP));`

Then this problem disappears.

2. But then at the time of free()ing  I get double free / corruption at core dump.

I am damn sure I am going wrong somewhere. I do not expect someone to correct my code and I just run it. Just hints would do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see a couple of problems:

- `ppColors` is an array of pointers.  Each element in the array is a `COLORMAP*` so you need to calculate the size to be malloced using `numElements * sizeof(COLORMAP*)`.  `COLORMAP` is just 3 chars so its likely that `sizeof(COLORMAP*)` > `sizeof(COLORMAP)`.  Your current allocation will be too small so you'll end up writing beyond the end of the array; this has undefined effects but is likely to crash.
- use of width & height are reversed between allocations and loops so you'll end up writing to unallocated memory at some point in your loops.

Comment: yeah.. problem was 1st bullet point. for the 2nd bullet pt -> sorry I had edited the code just before posting.. and posted 'as is'.. But I still have not understood why `sizeof(COLORMAP*)`..? Can you elaborate little more..?

Comment: @Adorn Glad that helped.  I've had a go at updating my answer.  Let me know if its still not clear.

Answer (score 3):

A pointer to a pointer is *not* the same as an array of arrays.

When using a pointer-to-pointer to simulate a multi-dimensional array, like this declaration:

```
char **pointer;
```

the memory looks like this:

```
+------------+------------+-----+-------------------+
| pointer[0] | pointer[1] | ... | pointer[size - 1] |
+------------+------------+-----+-------------------+
     |            |                  |
     v            v                  v
   Data         Data               Data
```

While a proper multi-dimensional array

```
char array[X][Y];
```

looks like this in memory:

```
+-------------+-------------+-----+-----------------+-------------+-----+
| array[0][0] | array[0][1] | ... | array[0][Y - 1] | array[1][0] | ... |
+-------------+-------------+-----+-----------------+-------------+-----+
```

So in a proper multi-dimensional array all the memory is in one single block, while using pointer-to-pointer you have an array of pointers and not an array of arrays.

---

So what you should do is allocate all sub-arrays separately:

```
ppColors = malloc(pHeader->height * sizeof(COLORMAP *));
/* Note how I allocate the width times the size of a COLORMAP pointer */

for (int i = 0; i < pHeader->height; i++)
    ppColors[i] = malloc(pHeader->width * sizeof(COLORMAP));
```

Don't forget that you now have to call `free` in a loop too!

Answer (score 1):

This may not be an answer but probably help you along with other answers.

- This might be problem with `fread` check what do you get in `pHeader -> height` and `pHeader -> width`
- Use parenthesis around `pHeader -> width` in `malloc(pHeader -> width * sizeof(COLORMAP))`